# Visualize scatterplot of only 2 variables with classification hue

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

*Been a while since I used seaborn.*

I am looking to plot a seaborn plot akin to what would be a product of:

```
sns.pairplot(iris, hue='species', size=2)
```

...with only two of the columns in the dataset WHILE retaining the hue "species".
This, in pseudo-python, would look like:

```
sns.pairplot(( iris['petal_width'], iris['petal_length'] ), hue='species')
```

Without some un-pythonic data manipulation, what is the correct way to do to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was looking for

```
sns.relplot(data=iris, x='petal_width', y='petal_length', hue='species', size=2)
```

Alternatively, one could do

```
sns.pairplot(data=iris, vars=['petal_width', 'pedal_length'], hue='species', size=2)
```

for an actual pairplot, but my first method was the goal I was seeking to accomplish.